# Control motor speed with mqtt on_message python

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt, global, paho

With the code I have now i can recieve the mqtt messages and run the motors using the `on_message` function in paho.mqtt. The problem is that the function `pwmb.ChangeDutyCycle(spd)` is not being called. My guess is that the function `on_message` can't access the `pwmb` variable. I've tryied to put the flag `global` inside the `on_message` and also to pass the variable through `userdata`. It apperently worked and I could even print the variable (in both cases), but the function `pwmb.ChangeDutyCycle(spd)` still won't run (i've cheked with prints and the thread stops as soon as it has to run this line of code). I'm attaching my code and the output below:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)      # Set GPIO mode to BCM
GPIO.setwarnings(False);

# PWM Frequency
pwmFreq = 100
# Setup Pins for motor controllers
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)    # PWMA  19
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)    # AIN2  21
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)    # AIN1  23
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)    # STBY  24 
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)    # BIN1  29
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)    # BIN2  26
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)    # PWMB  31

pwma = GPIO.PWM(12, pwmFreq)    # pin 18 to PWM  
pwmb = GPIO.PWM(11, pwmFreq)    # pin 13 to PWM

pwma.start(100)
pwmb.start(100)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("r2b2/7/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Msg: "+str(msg.payload)+str(userdata))
    if msg.payload == "stop": motorStop()
    if msg.payload[:3] == "mBF":#1
        m1(msg.payload[4:],userdata)
    if msg.payload[:3] == "mRF":#2
        m2(msg.payload[4:],userdata)


def m2(spd,userdata):
    runMotor(0,spd,0,userdata)

def m1(spd,userdata):
    runMotor(1,spd,0,userdata)

def runMotor(motor, spd, direction,userdata):
    pwmb=userdata
    global pwma
    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH);
    in1 = GPIO.HIGH
    in2 = GPIO.LOW

    if(direction == 1):
        in1 = GPIO.LOW
        in2 = GPIO.HIGH

    if(motor == 1):#motor n1
        print("runMotor1"+spd+str(pwmb))
        GPIO.output(15, in1)
        GPIO.output(13, in2)
        print("THIS RUNS")
        pwmb.ChangeDutyCycle(spd)
        print("THIS DOESN'T")
    elif(motor == 0):#motor n2
        print("runMotor2"+spd+str(pwma))
        GPIO.output(16, in1)
        GPIO.output(18, in2)
        print("THIS RUNS")
        pwma.ChangeDutyCycle(spd)
        print("THIS DOESN'T")

def motorStop():
    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)

def main(args=None):
    # Create an MQTT client and attach our routines to it.
    client = mqtt.Client(userdata=pwmb)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(ipR2B2, 1883, 60)
    client.loop_start()

    while True:
         #loop
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

PRINT I GET WHEN I RUN MOTOR #1 (using the `userdata` parameter):

```
Connected with result code 0
Msg: mBF 50<RPi.GPIO.PWM object at 0xb62b82c0>
runMotor150<RPi.GPIO.PWM object at 0xb62b82c0>
THIS RUNS
Msg: mBF 50<RPi.GPIO.PWM object at 0xb62b82c0>
runMotor150<RPi.GPIO.PWM object at 0xb62b82c0>
THIS RUNS
Msg: mBF 50<RPi.GPIO.PWM object at 0xb62b82c0>
runMotor150<RPi.GPIO.PWM object at 0xb62b82c0>
THIS RUNS
```

So my motor is always running at 100% which is the initial value (defined at `pwmb.start(100)`).

Changing the speed works if i call everything motor related from my `main()` function, so my guess is that the on_message has something to do with it.

Comment: Have you tried using `global pwmb` rather than passing it in as `userdata`? Also the `on_message` callback is happening on the MQTT client network thread not the main thread.

Comment: Yes, i've tryied it with the pwma and running the other motor, but it still doesn't get pass the `changeDutyCicle(spd)`... I can also print it.
What do you mean? I've tried to put the client initialitzation in outside the main() but I have the same problem.I really don't get why i can't use that function.

Comment: The `changeDutyCycle(spd)` worked for me if I putted the `pwma=GPIO.PWM(12, pwmFreq)` and the `pwma.start(100)` inside the `runMotor()` function. But the motor went kinda crazy